Could not find the way to resolve SSL certificate verification issue, for downloading TensorFlow 1.12.0
I am using tensorflow 2.16.1 but for my project purpose i have to degrade it to 1.12.0. For this I downloaded python 3.7.9 which was not suitable for tensorflow 1.12.0, so again I downloaded python 3.5.4 which is suitable for the required version of tensorflow.
This time I'm getting error for SSL certificate verification issue. For fixing this issue I updated pip and setup tools, and tried to download it by following command
"pip install tensorflow==1.12.0 --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org". But the error is same, can you please give me a suggestion to download the tensorflow 1.12.0 by using different way?
I am trying to upgrade setup tools, also tried pip3 install tensorflow -gpu==1.12.0, but the following error is same
^Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/tensorflow-gpu/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:719) - skipping

downgrading versions is poor practice.

the proposed version is several versions back !!

@D.L thankyou for your reply. Do you have any idea like what else I can do?
